# Google Sheets default column and rows does not scroll with sheet movement

Tags: google-sheets, scroll, settings

I have been trying hard to solve for an issue with a Google Sheet Tab but unable to find any solution online. In one of my Google Sheet I am unable to find a setting that can remove the restriction on default column and row names to not scroll with inner sheet movement.
The issue might get much clear from the video where you can see that while I scroll the sheet horizontally or vertically, the default column and rows are not moving but remain static.
Here is the video link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q3GUJUJR_w5ojnW0IQv32zNDptNjIQNg/view?usp=sharing

Please suggest how can this be resolved ?

The Google Sheet Tab is a multi-pivot dashboard to track certain metrics for my Business (Multiple regions). There are about 9 pivots and some additional data points with advanced excel functions.

Edit1: Earlier link got timed-out. Added from the drive.

Comment: It would be easier for us to debug your issue if you can provide a sample spreadsheet. Try to replicate your issue to another spreadsheet and use dummy data. Please see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to replicate the sheet to share with you guys as a sample, but as soon as I deleted some of the data, the google sheet started to work / scroll normally. I guess there is no setting change, but some bulk data is the trigger for a bug.